# How to get the location of an event in Google Calendar through the Google Calendar API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, location, google-calendar-api

as mentioned in the title I would like to get the location of an event in Google Calendar through the Google Calendar API in Javascript. Therefore I used the Google API sample.

```
/**
 * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
 * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
 * appropriate message is printed.
 */
function listUpcomingEvents() {
    gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
        'showDeleted': false,
        'singleEvents': true,
        'location': '--4-Bikini Bottom (12)',
        'maxResults': 10,
        'orderBy': 'startTime'


    }).then(function (response) {
        var events = response.result.items;
        appendPre('Upcoming events:');

        if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                var event = events[i];
                var when = event.start.dateTime;
                if (!when) {
                    when = event.start.date;
                }
                appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
            }
        } else {
            appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
        }
    });
}
```

Now the part that does not work is 'location'. I am able to get the dates and name of the next 10 calendar events but not the location. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommendation:**

I have replicated your code by following the guide from [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js) and reviewing the additional info from [Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events). I was able to tweak one of the `appendPre()` lines by adding `event.location` to show the location of the upcoming test event that I've created on my calendar, as shown here:

```
  function listUpcomingEvents() {
    gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 10,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    }).then(function(response) {
      var events = response.result.items;
      appendPre('Upcoming events:');

      if (events.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var event = events[i];
          var when = event.start.dateTime;
          if (!when) {
            when = event.start.date;
          }
          appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')\n'+'Location: '+event.location)
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Here's the result:

[image]